# send reference qplaintextedit to C++ constructor class

Tags: c++, qt, pointers, constructor, qplaintextedit

I need to send reference a `QPlainTextEdit` to my C++ class `Analizador` for add lines to `QPlainTextEdit` from my class. I add the include `<QPlainTextEdit>` to the class, create the `QPlainTextEdit` from the graphic interface and call the constructor function just like that

```
Analizador *anal=new Analizador(ui->textProgres);
```

the constructor function is:

```
Analizador(QPlainTextEdit* text);
```

the compiler throw the error :

> mainwindow.cpp:23: error: undefined reference to
>   `Analizador::Analizador(QPlainTextEdit*)'

so I guess the error is because I'm not sending a pointer to the constructor function but I don't know how to access the pointers of `QPlainTextEdit`

PS. I'm new in Qt and C++

Comment: That's a linker error and it's because you declared the constructor and either didn't define it or the file it's defined in is not being compiled or linked.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In this case, compiler complains that it cannot find the definition of `Analizador` constructor when it tries to link your application.

Make sure you have written the definition of `Analizador::Analizador(QPlainTextEdit*)` constructor.

If you have written the constructor but still you gets this issue, The cpp file where your constructor exists may not have got compiled. If you are using QtCreator, try `Build -> Run QMake` and then `Build -> Rebuild All`

Answer (score 1):

You can try this workaround.

```
#ifndef ANALIZADOR_H
#define ANALIZADOR_H

#include <QPlainTextEdit>

class Analizador
{
public:
    Analizador(QPlainTextEdit *text)
    {
        plainTextEdit = text;
    }

    void addLines(QString line)
    {
        plainTextEdit->appendPlainText(line);
    }

private:
    QPlainTextEdit *plainTextEdit;
};

#endif // ANALIZADOR_H
```

And use this class like this.

```
analizador = new Analizador(ui->plainTextEdit);
analizador->addLines("Hello");
analizador->addLines("World");
```